# how to reload in Gmail when vertical split is set?

Tags: gmail

I like to set Gmail with vertical split so I can see my email list and the email content simultaneously. The problem is that when I do so, I cant see anymore the reload button and it is quite annoying.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Qsu.png)

Does someone now how can I add the reload button to that bar?

I tried to google this topic but couldn't really find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is to click on the "inbox" folder button on the left and I believe that reloads the emails also. (or just reload the page entirely)

Option 2 is to "unread" and then "reread" the email you currently have selected (with the button on the email itself when you hover over it on the left side of the vertical split), which keeps it "read" but removes it from the right side of the vertical split. When there is no email open, the content bar has the reload button on it.

I personally don't know if there's a way to keep the reload button on there always, if someone else does that would be great!